# Taxonomies, Adanced Custom Fields and Repeatable Fields

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

Using ACF I've added a taxomomy with a repeatable field. I've followed the instructions on the [ACF support page](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/) to get it to output with no luck. I did wonder if the fact that the $taxonomy_name has an underscore so the post_id is taxonomy_name_1.

The code is as follows.

```
<?php
  $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
  $term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
  $taxonomy_name = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ); 
  $post_id = "{$taxonomy_name}_{$term_id}";
?>

<?php if( have_rows('right_column_box', '$post_id') ): ?>8<?php else: ?>12<?php endif; ?>">
```

and

```
<?php if( have_rows('right_column_box', '$post_id') ): ?>
  <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs">

    <?php while ( have_rows('right_column_box', '$post_id') ) : the_row();

    $image = get_sub_field('image', '$post_id');
    $content = get_sub_field('content', '$post_id');

    ?>
          <div class="right-block">
            <div class="right-block-image"><img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" /></div>
            <div class="right-block-content">
              <?php echo $content; ?>
            </div>
          </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `have_rows()` calls, you put the `$post_id` variable in a single-quoted string - which is wrong.

It should be `have_rows( 'right_column_box', $post_id )`.

**// Edit**
Of course, this is also true for the `get_sub_field()` calls.